# Pandas Sub-Heading

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a question regarding creating a DataFrame using Pandas with Python. So I am scraping a data that has a "main header" and then a sub-heading.

Just like this one:
[weather temprature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGBKb.png)

when I **scrape** it, basically I will have a string, I was able to separate the data, but now I wanna construct it in a data frame to be exactly the same as in the source (the image).. so is there a way to construct the data using pandas and tell it I have a main column name after that I have a sub-column name then the data will be under each sub-column name.

I have tried to make a nested dictionary but the result wasn't as I was expecting:
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1jtO.png)

I got the sub-column name as an index instead.

Comment: Add code, errors, and data as text, not screenshots because [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It is likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and add text.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered here and provides a solution:

[Pandas how to read sub headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871136/pandas-how-to-read-sub-headers)

Having a look though they manipulated the data frame so that the sub headers became another indexed value. To then access that column you then perform the selection

```
df[('Header1', 'Subheader1-1')]
```

As an alternative you can use a tuples dictionary to get the same result which is slightly easier/cleaner. This is from the pandas documentation

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({('a', 'b'): {('A', 'B'): 1, ('A', 'C'): 2},('a', 'a'): 
{('A', 'C'): 3, ('A', 'B'): 4},('a', 'c'): {('A', 'B'): 5, ('A', 'C'): 6},
('b', 'a'): {('A', 'C'): 7, ('A', 'B'): 8},('b', 'b'): {('A', 'D'): 9, ('A',
'B'): 10}})

print(df)

       a              b      
       b    a    c    a     b
A B  1.0  4.0  5.0  8.0  10.0
  C  2.0  3.0  6.0  7.0   NaN
  D  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   9.0
```

Comment: can you select columns based on subheadings?