# In Python, what is the panda syntax to select a subheader from a table being pulled from a url?

Tags: python, html, pandas, html-table, header

```
Headers:          Volume       Energy        Enthalpy      
Subheaders:       vf  vg       uf  ug      hf  hfg  hg
```

For example: If I wanted to select [Enthalpy, hfg] I would expect something like this:

```
df = pd.read_html('url', header=[2,1])
```

[I used this post as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871136/pandas-how-to-read-sub-headers), but this didn't work.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_data_from_webpage(url):# This returns a list of dataframes
    
    t_table = pd.read_html(url, header=1)
   
    return t_table[0]

result = get_data_from_webpage('http://ouopentextbooks.org/thermodynamics/saturation-properties-temperature-table/') # Url with table being passed through function.

print(result)
```

From here I would like to select the temp column to use as a key and then put the rest of the corresponding row into a lookup table. Then when the user inputs the key, it outputs the corresponding row of values.

Final result would work like:

****User inputs**:** 20

**Output:** vf, uf, hf, and sf values

Comment: upload your dataset or a sample of it

Comment: I didn't want to as I was trying to keep my answer as concise as possible http://ouopentextbooks.org/thermodynamics/saturation-properties-temperature-table/

Comment: how do you get the dataset from that website? did you manually copy-paste that table into an excel csv file or you used a web crawler?....... and do you want the answer to include the process of the web-crawling? if yes please add that to your question otherwise if you dont want want web-crawling please upload the dataset you manually copy-pasted as a csv (not excel). you can copy-paste the csv's plaintext contents here or upload it externally.

Comment: .. no I read the url. In the panada library it can read tables from a website. ```df = pd.read_html('url')
len(df)```will output there is only one table to read from. I just want to know the syntax to read a specific header in a table with subheaders

Comment: could you post your full code so far. so that it is easier for people to help you. without code, others have to start from scratch if they want to help you.

Comment: I made my post more complete. Thank you sir for taking a look.

Comment: Thanks for making your post complete. I did what you wanted. Take a look and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I did a solution. But, you might have to do `pip install Unidecode` first to install the the necessary libraries.

I used alphabets for the index so as to not confuse the users since the columns are numerical.

Here is the output:

```
List of available temperatures:

AA) 000.01
AB) 005.00
AC) 010.00
AD) 015.00
AE) 020.00
AF) 025.00
AG) 030.00
AH) 035.00
AI) 040.00
AJ) 045.00
AK) 050.00
AL) 055.00
AM) 060.00
AN) 065.00
AO) 070.00
AP) 075.00
AQ) 080.00
AR) 085.00
AS) 090.00
AT) 095.00
AU) 100.00
AV) 110.00
AW) 120.00
AX) 130.00
AY) 140.00
AZ) 150.00
BA) 160.00
BB) 170.00
BC) 180.00
BD) 190.00
BE) 200.00
BF) 210.00
BG) 220.00
BH) 230.00
BI) 240.00
BJ) 250.00
BK) 260.00
BL) 270.00
BM) 280.00
BN) 290.00
BO) 300.00
BP) 310.00
BQ) 320.00
BR) 330.00
BS) 340.00
BT) 350.00
BU) 360.00
BV) 370.00
BW) 373.95

Enter a temperature (in degrees celsius) from the available options above: 250

vf is: 0.0012519999999999999
uf is: 1080.8
hf is: 1085.8
sf is: 2.7935
```

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from unidecode import unidecode
import itertools
import string
import sys

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as fp:
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            pass
    return i + 1

def excel_cols():
    n = 1
    while True:
        yield from (''.join(group) for group in itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=n))
        n += 1

def remove_and_exit(temp13,temp12=0):
    try:
        os.remove("test.csv")
    except:
        pass
    if temp13:
        sys.exit(temp12)

def get_data_from_webpage(url):# This returns a list of dataframes

    t_table = pd.read_html(url, header=1)

    return t_table[0]

result = get_data_from_webpage('http://ouopentextbooks.org/thermodynamics/saturation-properties-temperature-table/') # Url with table being passed through function.

result.index.rename('index', inplace=True)


new_columns = result.columns.values
for temp1 in range(len(new_columns)):
    new_columns[temp1] = unidecode(new_columns[temp1])
result.columns  = new_columns

remove_and_exit(False)

result.to_csv("test.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8')

temp2 = []

with open("test.csv") as file_in:
    for line in file_in:
        temp2.append(line.strip())

temp5 = list(itertools.islice(excel_cols(), file_len("test.csv")+26))
temp5 = temp5[26:-1]

temp6 = -1 #before decimal
temp7 = -1 #after decimal

print("List of available temperatures:\n")
for temp3 in range(len(temp2)): #temp5[temp3-1]
    if temp3 == 0:
        continue
    if (len(temp2[temp3].split(",")[1].split(".")[0])) > temp6:
        temp6 = len(temp2[temp3].split(",")[1].split(".")[0])
    if (len(temp2[temp3].split(",")[1].split(".")[1])) > temp7:
        temp7 = len(temp2[temp3].split(",")[1].split(".")[1])

for temp8 in range(len(temp2)): #temp5[temp8-1]
    if temp8 == 0:
        continue
    print(temp5[temp8-1]+") "+temp2[temp8].split(",")[1].split(".")[0].zfill(temp6)+"."+temp2[temp8].split(",")[1].split(".")[1].ljust(temp7, '0'))


temp4 = input("\nEnter a temperature (in degrees celsius) from the available options above: ")

try:
    temp9 = float(temp4)
except:
    print("\nYou did not enter a temperature (in degrees celsius)")
    remove_and_exit(True,11)
temp11 = False
for temp10 in range(len(temp2)):
    if temp10 == 0:
        continue
    if temp9 == float(temp2[temp10].split(",")[1]):
        print("")
        print("vf is: "+temp2[temp10].split(",")[3])
        print("uf is: "+temp2[temp10].split(",")[5])
        print("hf is: "+temp2[temp10].split(",")[7])
        print("sf is: "+temp2[temp10].split(",")[10])
        temp11 = True
        break
if not temp11:
    print("\nYou did not enter a value from the available options above")
    remove_and_exit(True,1761)
remove_and_exit(True)
```